# Is a wood-core sword the best use of the metal?

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons, materials

I am currently reading the *Steerswoman* series by Rosemary Kirstein, and the second book introduces us to a unique weapon used by Outskirter tribes who have very little access to metal. Rather than forging swords entirely out of steel, they carve a wooden core with a horn grip and then press-fit a sharpened band of steel around the edge.

This is sort of the same idea as an Aztec macahuitl, but more sword-like and less club-like, and replacing the obsidian with steel. But while a macahuitl is an obvious synergy, improving a club with sharp bits and improving a small obsidian blade with reach, it is less obvious that this is a good idea for a thing to do with limited supplies of steel.

So, is this actually a viable idea?

Comment: What is the exact shape of this weapon? Can you successfully stub someone with it?

Comment: If they have limited supplies of steel they could just weld a steel edge onto an iron sword. For that matter, they could just use iron swords, skipping the steel altogether. After all, *everybody* used plain iron swords for about a thousand years. It worked for the Romans, it would certainly work for the Out Skirters.

Comment: @Alexander if the sword is heavy enough, one can easily stub one's toe :)

Comment: @AlexP There is a general lack of access to metal, not just steel; one handle-less metal knife blade is considered worth more than several livestock animals in the story.

Comment: I swear I've seen a weapon made of a big long wooden thing, and a tiny metal pointy thing on the end.... I suspect that such a pole-based-arm would be the optimum metal/wood ratio.

Comment: @Aron don't shake it, lest you want to write theater pieces and sonnets.

Comment: What's wrong with a spear?

Comment: swords don't actually need that much metal. if you can make a metal blade capable cutting you can make a sword out of it.

Comment: @AlexP lack of steel implies lack of iron (except for special magic steel as in GoT where this could be interesting - and I think has been asked).  A bronze backbone would also be interesting, but could perhaps be cast in place, or brazed on - except it's metal in general that's missing, not just ferrous metal

Comment: @DKNguyen Presumably, the fact that most fantasy and historical fiction writers don't know how to write a spear v. sword duel. (Not that most of them know how to write sword v. sword, either, but at least there's enough pop culture reference that they think they do.)

Comment: @Chris: Lack of steel most definitely does not imply lack of iron. People had been using iron for many centuries before the use of steel became common. For example, steel was somewhere between unknown and very uncommon in the classical Greco-Roman world, but iron was plentiful. (Steel did become less uncommon and merely very expensive towards the end of the antiquity.) (That's because producing iron is quite easy with very primitive technology. Producing steel is something else entirely.)

Answer (score 24):

> improving a club with sharp bits

The classic solution to having access to a stick and a small amount of sharp stuff was to make a spear out of it. The pattern has been repeated across many civilizations using many different materials across a very wide span of time (from about a quarter of a million years ago, to Napoleonic lancers, for example). It works well with a wide range of skills and military tactics.

Producing and maintaining a spearhead is a relatively straightfoward task compared to a sword blade, and the old pointed-stick design can be extended to things that get thrown (probably in an emergency, given the value of the material in your case) or things that can be used effectively from horseback in the form of a lance.

Other than spears we have axes and picks which are perhaps a little closer to the "sharp club" idea you're looking at. Both easier to make, easier to repair and maintain that the steel-edged wooden sword idea, both tested on the battlefield.

> Outskirter tribes who have very little access to metal

How do they *make* the steel edge? Creating and working steel is a relatively complex technical task, and it seems mildly surprising that they'd have almost no metal but a comparatively advanced skill with the forge. I'd have thought they'd be much more likely to use stolen or traded steel weapons, or work with more forgiving materials like bronze.

Comment: I’ve always loved how the spear is such a common, convergent solution to the problem of ‘I want to stick a sharp thing into something that is far away’

Comment: How they make it is a good question! If it gets answered over the next three books, I'll try to come back here and mention it...

Comment: Incidentally, they do *also* use stolen and traded steel weapons.

Comment: +1 for spear, seems to be the most effective solution possible. Uses a very small amount of metal and only puts it in spots where it has maximum effect.

Comment: Also should note that for many (most?) ancient/medieval armies, sword was a secondary weapon to spear (or other polearm) even if all soldiers were equipped with a sword, because the longer reach of the polearm is hugely advantageous.

Comment: While not necessarily relevant to the WB question, the *Steerswoman* series has a premise of lost technology being hidden as magic, so it is quite possible that the techniques and tricks for steelworking have been passed down without as much need to experimentation with the limited quantities of steel.

Comment: Do they have access to stone?  A good hard stone could make an effective anvil (and possibly a hammer) if metal is unavailable, but would not be great for making the blades themselves.  (Stone blades exist, e.g. aforementioned Aztec macahuitl, but it's not feasible to make an entire sword out of stone, as it would either be too heavy or too brittle.)

Comment: @MartinModrák I would go so far as to call the spear the second-most important weapon in the history of human warfare, behind only the firearm. Swords got romanticized. Spears won wars.

Comment: Don't forget about the mace. That could be just metal barbs or stakes sticking out of a wooden ball or bat. The downside is that the stakes would likely break their mounting points and make the mace useless, or at least not-pointy, after a few swings.

Comment: To summarize all the excellent points above. Short of metal? Forget swords etc. Go with (in no specific order of importance ) spears, maces/hammers and arrow heads. And back them up with good old fashioned slings using fired clay or dense stone for shot. Also like the Aztec etc if you can find deposits of obsidian, flint quartz and similar rock you can craft highly effective javelin (atlatl) and arrow heads. (Historically atlatl heads are recorded as having  piecing conquistador breast plates) They're 'one shot's  i.e. you wont recover the spear or arrow head but needs must.

Comment: Sharpening also wastes metal, so a point (spear) needing sharpening is less wasteful than the long edge of a sword.  Something like a mini spear could serve a bit like a dagger at close quarters. Bladed polearms might be suitable for an elite - more metal, not to be wasted on conscripts, but more effective

Answer (score 15):

No, it won't work. Wood moves with the moisture; first rain and the wood will swell, 2-3 days after with a nice weather and the *pressed* strip of metal falls off.

BTW, wood swell/shrink mostly on the [radial and tangential direction](https://www.swedishwood.com/wood-facts/about-wood/wood-and-moisture/moisture-related-wood-movement/). Better (or worse) yet, the wood is stronger along the fiber, so you *will* press your strip on a tangential direction - the direction most affected by the movement with the moisture

> For practical calculations, 7% can be used as the average figure for movement in sawn pine and spruce timber, which corresponds to 0.24% per 1 percentage point change in the moisture content.

> Example: A 145 mm wide floorboard with a moisture content of 17% is laid in a room with a climate equating to the wood’s equilibrium moisture content of 10%. The change in moisture content is 17−10 = 7 percentage points. The board shrinks 7 x 0.0026 x 145 mm = approx. 2.6 mm in width.

---

While not as durable as a metal sword, wooden swords as weapons [aren't a thing to be laughed out of the door](https://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/gadgets/a25329/wooden-sword-joerg-sprave/)

> To explore the actual damage-dealing potential of a wooden sword, slingshot master and unorthodox weapon engineer Joerg Sprave whipped one up from a log and began putting it through its paces. The results are pretty impressive. Wood can do some real damage against cardboard, cloth, and ballistics gel, even though it can't be sharpened to a hair-splitting edge and loses whatever edge it does have very, very quickly.

Comment: Maybe they keep their wooden swords soaked in oil.  They drip when you take them out of the scabbard so the hilt is shaped like a cup.   That would prevent water from messing with them and also be good vs rust.  If it were red palm oil that would also be a scary look.

Comment: @Willk I like it. Don't take it out from the scabbard too often, you'll run out of oil. Even better, use it together and while in the scabbard - if the strip fells, it wouldn't matter anyway. Speaking for myself, I'd rather use a shiv made from that strip of steel.

Comment: Just attach the metal and wood parts together so it doesn't fall off.  For example use rivets through the metal, wood, and then out the metal on the other side. The wood might change shape but the metal can also change shape. Probably leave a small gap for the wood to expand anyway.

Comment: @Daron yeah, nah, mate. You ain't a woodworker, it shows. Drive a nail, rivet or anything you like on a thin piece of wood, you end by splitting it, especially if the row of fasteners follows the wood fiber. Which means you'll need a wider strip - to reach the thicker "meat" of the blade. Which means you'll compress a wider piece of wood which expands more. So, what now? You leave a larger gap between the wood core and the strip of steel? If so, why do still call it a core? For your [viewing pleasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rUwCiR2aKY)

Comment: Musashi famously carved a wooden oar into a sword and killed someone with it in a duel. It can be made to work at least once.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi There is also such a thing as glue.

Comment: Notably, macahuitl apparently used some kind of adhesive to keep the obsidian blades attached to the wooden handle. It sounds weirdly impractical to me, and yet it apparently worked quite well.

Comment: @Daron you heavily underestimate the force of wood stretching. There is a reason why in a concrete or brick building you always leave about a centimeter / half an inch gap between wooden floor and the wall. If you will glue it, either wood or glue is going to crack. Macuahuitl has only short pieces of obsidian glued in and is short overall, so force per piece is small. Attach a continuous blade to something as long as European longsword, and you are asking for trouble. 7% of 3cm is ~2mm. Short enough for bitumen to compensate. For a longsword 7% may mean 10cm of change. Not happening.

Comment: @Mołot The floor of my kitchen is made of pieces of wood longer than a sword and they do not change length by 10cm with the weather.

Comment: @Daron glue, you say? Need to be an elastic glue, with a certain amount of "give" after setting. In a world were the metals are scarce, the only [low-tech glue](https://baynebox.com/news/the-history-of-glue/) is [hide glue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_glue) - works exceptionally fine for luthiers, but it's brittle (so it will fail at shocks), mildly water-resistant (keep your objects dry), subject to biodegradation (have some disinfectant with you) and performs poorly on metal. Forget about starch or gluten based glues, they are good mainly for paperwork, not small contact areas.

Comment: "Drive a nail, rivet or anything you like on a thin piece of wood, you end by splitting it" - which is why you drill the wood first and have the mechanical stress be on the metal only

Comment: @Whelkaholism even if you do use pilot holes, you have a line of fasteners on the same or very close neighboring fibers. It is bound to weaken the wood quite significantly. And where's the weakness located? Exactly on what is supposed to be the striking edge. (disclaimer: I have woodworking as a hobby, for quite a long time).

Comment: "In a world were the metals are scarce, the only low-tech glue is hide glue" I'm pretty sure that there are also low-tech plant-based glues, given the existence of things like rubber trees.

Comment: @nick012000 2 questschs: 1. did you read the link on the "low-tech glue"? It is supposed to be "The History of Glue" - no mention of "plant based glue" there. 2. did you ever try to glue anything with rubber latex? How did it go?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi It sounds like you are suggesting that it is impossible to attach wood and metal together. But this can be done even without fancy modern materials. For example some pole weapons had metal langets, which look like a line of nails or rivets driven through the wooden shaft to secure a long strip of metal to either side. But you said the grain of the wood makes that a bad idea. So I don't know what to think on the matter.

Comment: @Daron I'm saying you can't attach, with primitive technologies, a long strip of steel on the _thin edge_ of what is meant to be the striking side of a wooden sword. I mean, you can if you want to, but it fail as a sword. Even more, if you look at the description in the OP, the way of fixing it is described as "press fitting" - no fasteners or glue.

Comment: And today, this comes out: https://arstechnica.com/science/2021/10/watch-this-wooden-knife-cut-effortlessly-through-juicy-medium-well-done-steak/. The tech wouldn't have been out of the reach of an alchemist, but the things they happened to stumble on were, in our world, different. In an alternate history, though...

Comment: @JohnDoty see? No steel needed.

Answer (score 10):

Wood and metal are not very good mechanical friends, except for putting a round bit of wood in a round hole in the metal, or vice versa. Handles or shafts, basically. That is not what we need here though.

The thermal expansion ratios differ too much, the response to water differs enormously. Wood *loves* to absorb water and expand!

However, not all is lost!

If you only want a nice cutting edge, and rely *purely* on the wood to provide the structural body, then you can use something like this:
[image]

We are all familiar with this simple technique to put a really sharp cutting edge onto a very much non-cutting structure.

I've managed to cut my thumb to the bone on a simple aluminium foil dispenser, imagine what you could manage of you put a strip of this along the edge of a nice Bokken.

Your metals strip will need to be demountable, replaceable and reforgeable, because with its extreme thinness it *will* take damage in any fight.

Consider the extreme example of this technique: a safety razor. That is a *lot* of sharp edge, using very little metal indeed. Now just juggle the layout a bit to remove the "safety" aspect.

Comment: Upvoted for using an excellent example of combining two crappy items to make a pretty dangerous hybrid. Those foil boxes are lethal.

Comment: For another hybrid of a similar design look at where the name "Peaky Blinders" actually comes from

Answer (score 4):

One quick but critical point before getting into the details. Metal blades tend to be *really* thin, often as much as structurally possible, so this question really boils down to: can wood actually help you make an effective blade with even less metal?

---

I think the biggest issue is the use of a wooden **core**. Combining wood and metal is certainly nothing new (there are plenty of historical weapons that use metal sparingly) but this approach would undermine the advantages of both materials.

We can look at the fascinating (and very effective) wooden weapons developed by Maori communities before they had access to metal. Even thin wood weapons like the wahaika below that provide highly concentrated impact (seriously, these *really* hurt and can definitely be lethal) are still much thicker than sword blades.

[image: The edge of a Maori wahaika]
([image source](https://www.arthurbeaupalmer.com/cms/gallery/maori/13-consultant-investment-fine-and-tribal-art/maori/111-maori-wahaika-tiki-war-club))

A wooden core would probably have to be quite thick to sufficiently handle weapon impact. A thin wooden core, or even just a thin wooden edge on a thicker wooden core, would raise a lot of durability issues when creating a sword-like weapon. Imagine applying metal film on thin wooden chips - I can't think of a way to make that simultaneously sharp and strong. You need to make it relatively thick.

What makes a good sword blade? The complete opposite. To cut effectively, you want very thin, flat blades (not a thick wedge). You would lose a lot of cutting capacity by making it thicker - consider wood axes, which are great at splitting wood but terrible at cutting. A combat axe will feature a *much* thinner flat blade like the Dane axe (11th century replica) below.

[image: A modern replica of an 11th century Dane axe]
([image source](https://www.arms-n-armor.com/collections/axes/products/danish-axe))

In short: I can't imagine how this kind of design could be thin enough to cut effectively and while still being durable enough to be practical. You are much better off with a proper metal blade - even a small, thin one - mounted on a wooden body.

---

So, what do you do when you make an effective weapon with only a bit of metal? Throughout history and across the world, this is where pole arms really shine! As several others mentioned, the spear family is probably the thriftiest way to combine a bit of metal with a wooden body. There's a reason they remained the most common infantry weapon for millennia (vastly underrepresented in modern media, but don't let that fool you).

[image: Some examples of various pole arms, featuring different advantages and manufacturing requirements]

However, since they are perhaps the *least* sword-like pole arm, I wanted to add that you can reclaim some cutting capacity with larger (but still relatively small) metal blades. The glaive family is essentially various knives mounted on wooden poles - a good way to get something closer to a sword without much metal (and an opportunity to *really* optimize, if you need to).

[image: A few different glaive designs, demonstrating a pretty variable use of metal]
([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Glaives_by_Wendelin_Boeheim.jpg))

It's hard to pick a single best design without a full understanding of the context, since that will determine the right tradeoff between cutting capacity vs metal quantity, but *something* on the broad spectrum of pole arms would be a much more effective way to combine a bit of metal with wood to create a practical (and sometimes vaguely sword-like) weapon.

Comment: Good answer, well documented and supported. Welcome to WB.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps instead of some sharp bits stuck onto the wooden sword, it could be more of a steel-clad sword with a wooden core, hilt, and handle.

Something where to the casual observer it would still appear to be an almost entirely metal sword.  I think a very dense hardwood like Leadwood, quebracho, or camelthorn would make for an excellent core. Hardwoods like these also tend to suffer less from shrinkage and expansion caused by changes in humidity.

As far as the edge goes, the outside of the sword would still be all metal so could be made to take as fine an edge as a standard metal sword.  Fastening could be done both mechanically using internal burs in the metal or with small screws and also with glues such as tar, sap or pitch.

Yes, it would still use more metal than just a strip stuck in a piece of wood, but it would save metal compared to a standard sword. Probably enough to make two swords out of one.

I could see this being more of a status symbol, (knock-off sword if you will) rather than a weapon intended for actual combat.  Although with the right construction it would still be effective as a weapon.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but keep in mind that in a technologically regressed civilization the availability of screws and availability of epoxy resin may be at the same level of [(im)possiblity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rUwCiR2aKY)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi As far as the epoxy goes, they can probably find some form of sap or tar that could be heated and poured which could become hard once it's cooled.

Comment: @agweber and this will help exactly how? Wood swells and shrinks with humidity, you'll end with a parade sword, not a weapon one can _rely_ in the outskirts. From the perspective of reliability and effectiveness, I'd prefer dropping the wood core and forging [a foil or a sabre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencing#Weapons) - that's only 500g of steel.

Answer (score 2):

No. It doesn't make much sense.

Sword is a sword because of its combined qualities. It's a piece of balanced metal giving you ability to cut, stab, block and has a certain fairly fixed ratio of durability to mass.

It's also expensive, requires training and has limited range.

Spear is simple, cheap, can be made with almost no metal and you can often kill someone with a sword before he can cut you. It's also damn hard to fight a spearman.

Sword becomes a deadly weapon in hands of someone in an armour, preferably on a horse. Other than that - spear.

Answer (score 2):

### Who needs METAL?  Just make a wooden sword. :)

[It's like a wooden steak knife](https://phys.org/news/2021-10-hardened-wooden-knives-slice-steak.html), only bigger.  Digest out the lignite, press down until it's 23 times harder than wood and 3 times sharper than a metal knife, coat in mineral oil.  I'll admit though, while it's impressive to drive wooden nail it is rather sad to watch how *slow* it is.  Miracles should be snappier.  I'm not sure how well the sword will really do - but at least you can make more!

Comment: And more environmentally friendly! ... Well, except for the tree, of course!

Comment: There was a series of fantasy books I read back in the eighties (I think Raymond E Feist had something to do with them, or possibly someone he wrote with), in which highly lacquered wooden swords were used by a pan-dimensional invading army. The lacquer was supposed to be super hard and obviously the weapons were much lighter than their metal counterparts, giving them ... the edge (ahem!) in battle.

Comment: @Paul The swords were made from laminated hides that had been stretched and scraped paper thin before being glued and pressed. It was from the Empire trilogy by Raymond E Feist. The swords and armor were not as good as steel but the Empire had virtually no metals at all.

Comment: @Thorne - Ah!  Hides!  Such a long time ago since I've read the series.  Thanks for that!  :o)

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the Aztec weapon called maquahuitl which was wood with a bunch of obsidian glued in. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macuahuitl

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ceremonial_Macuahuitl.jpg

Comment: the OP has said that the weapon is different from the maquahuitl : "more sword-like and less club-like"